# How to select a full year's Weekdays or Weekend in Full calendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How to select a week day or weekend in full calendar for one year?

I tried some answers from stack overflow.

```
 $('.fc-day.fc-mon').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
 $('.fc-day.fc-sat').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
```

This works for me,current month mon/sat selected, but when I click next/previous button or change month,my selection was gone.
Also I need to select for a whole year.? 
How to do it?
TIA

Comment: add style in CSS `.fc-day.fc-mon{ background-color: teal}` or do it always when changing the month

Comment: No I try to load for one whole year..Also this selection will be made only after I choose day.. So I individually write this code under each day selection. After selection my selection only must display for selected year only.. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code adding style to elements exists in the page when the code is executing but after changing month it will recreate new elements and destroys all existing so your update won't reflect in the newly created elements.

---

You have 2 options, if you want to it to be there always then you can add simple style in your CSS for those elements.

```
.fc-day.fc-mon,.fc-day.fc-sat{ 
  background-color: teal;
}
```

---

Or you have to do it always when new calendar view is rendered, you can do it within [`viewRender`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/viewRender) callback.

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
    $('.fc-day.fc-mon').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
    $('.fc-day.fc-sat').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
}
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can extract the year from `view.start` property(which holds moment date object) and based on the year set the class if necessary.

For example:

```
viewRender: function(view, element) {
  if (view.start.format('YYYY') === '2019') {
    $('.fc-day.fc-mon').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
    $('.fc-day.fc-sat').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
  }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();
  console.log(y + "-" + m + "-" + d);

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
      if (view.start.format('YYYY') === '2019') {
        $('.fc-day.fc-mon').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
        $('.fc-day.fc-sat').css('backgroundColor', 'teal');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: For the Css thing, I gave answer on ur first comment. THen I tried ur render view.. but Its not working for me..It asked me funciton Name so I gave some name, still not working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f2m4Lp0j/2/  I am new to fiddle.. I wrote my code there, but somehow,calendar didnt comeout.. Its my working code

Comment: @Riya your calendar didn't work in the JSFiddle because you haven't included any code to create or render a calendar. What you've included appears to be a subset of your working code. Nor have you included the fullCalendar CSS either. Also your previous fullCalendar questions have all been based on fullCalendar v3, but in this JSFiddle you added (some of) the v4 libraries. Please pay closer attention to the details of exactly what you are doing! If you want a working JSFiddle of v3, you can fork one of mine at http://jsfiddle.net/9a86h74m/ and amend it for your situation

Comment: @Riya actually to save you the time, since it's trivial, here is the amended version: http://jsfiddle.net/xp9vf3rk/1/. As you can see this idea using viewRender seems to work fine. What exactly did you find to be a problem with it? Perhaps you are wanting to check the view to see if (part of) it falls within your desired year? If so you can check it easily by examining `view.start` and `view.end`

Comment: @Riya LET ME CHECK

Comment: @Riya check the updated answer, added demo as well change it as per your need(replace the hardcoded year)

Comment: @PranavCBalan Hi, I tried ur reference in my fiddle too, its not working in fiddle.. I not sure with fiddle, but the code I added in fiddle is the one that working for me like I said earlier. But Now I tried  your view render method,same like u added in fiddle, but not yet working for me...

Comment: @PranavCBalan FYI, I am using jQuery 3,Bootstrap 3.3.7,jQuery UI 1.11.4, fullcalendar v 3.8.2,

Comment: @Riya :  where is your full calendar initialization code in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2m4Lp0j/2/ ???

Comment: Hi @PranavCBalan Here is my simple code `var date = new Date()
        var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear()
 var startdate = y+'-01-01';
 var enddate =y+'-12-31';
if (WDay1 == 'Wednesday') {
   for (k = startdate; k <= enddate; k++) 
 { 
 $('.fc-day.fc-wed').css('backgroundColor', '#800000');
  }
  }`  When  I click load button If I choose wednesday my `.fc-wed` class color changed for me, but the problem is it change only for current month, when I navigate through prev,next button, my selection was gone,

Comment: and here I never initiate my calendar, when I give `.fc-day-.fc-wed`, it automatically chose my calendar. and I tried your fiddle answer, dnt know y, its not working for me. For testing, I even hardcode the year in your answer,still not working. And I tried adding same resource link in my fiddle, but calendar nvr comeout in my fiddle,for that sorry, as I am unable to give you reference

Comment: @Riya :  fullcalendar is initializing somewhere else in ur code

Comment: @ADyson sry I replied to ur comment earlier, but I mentioned as Pranav sir name. yes, I may initialize my calendar at first, but as I send u a short codes, I may missed  it. Now I updated my code in your fiddle. here is the fiddle link..  http://jsfiddle.net/zw82jrhe/3/ - kindly check it, this is what I mentioned, and if I tried ur  view render  also, its not working for me. I even comment my codes, and used your exact code,still not working

Comment: @PranavCBalan Hi sir, ur code works fine in fiddle, but Its not working for me, When I debug I found out, it never goes in to the  `$('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({ });` function. I  am checking again and again, no error come out, only it skip this function, it automatically goes to the end braces. but thank u so much sir and @ADyson for ur replies... I am keep on trying this- to fix y it never works for me...

Comment: @Riya your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/zw82jrhe/3 does not use viewRender, which is why it doesn't do what you want it to - it only colours in the days in the currently visible month. If you tried a version with viewRender and had a problem, please show us a fiddle containing that which reproduces your error. We can't fix code which we cannot see.

Comment: @Riya :  I'd updated this line as well `var startday = y + '-01-01';
  var endday = y + '-12-31` (added `-` in date string)

Comment: @PranavCBalan Sir, Its not related to ur code, its working fine on ur fiddle, but for me only, its not working, I am not sure due to version pblm. Now check my question plz, I added the codes that tried under function Load() with ur code. Its directly from my code, I dnt know what I did wrong?coz same working in ur fiddle.  I added for 3 days only.

Comment: @Riya : do you have a live version of your project ?

Comment: oops sory.. live version means ?  live project ah?

Comment: @Riya :  ya something i can access remotely

Comment: @Riya if you cannot make a JSFiddle or other publicly viewable demo which reproduces your issue then it's very hard to help you. Alternatively, please at least add to the question all of your fullCalendar related code, and also tell us exactly what version you are using, and what JS/CSS files you have loaded. Also check your browser console for errors and mention in your question any which you encounter. Without some way of actually seeing your issue we really cannot help much further. "it's not working" is not information we can use to understand it. Try to do some more detailed debugging too

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197369/discussion-on-answer-by-pranav-c-balan-how-to-select-a-full-years-weekdays-or-w).